# jdbc connection - socket connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

A few days ago my website crashed and showed me this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class
>   com.omicc.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil

So I asked the hosting company about any changes that they may have made. They fixed the problem and told me to use JDBC connections instead of socket connections.
I am using hibernate and c3p0 with MySQL and as far as I know they use JDBC connections.

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

So do any of you guys know what he was talking about? :D (and yes he is not answering now!)

EDITED>>>>

Solved!, so here is what i did
i upgraded my hibernate from hibernate from 3.5.0 to 3.6.1
and new hibernate required hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar and slf4j-simple1.6.1 .
and problem solved.
i think that the hosting company updated their hibernate.jar and it  caused some reference problems.

Comment: JDBC uses tcp (it's layered on top of tcp). So, unless you've  implemented your jdbc stack (please say no), then their admonishment is more likely to be a cover-up for their own mistake(s).

Comment: Hibernate should have been using JDBC all along.  I have no idea what your hosting company is talking about.  I think the package is suspicious, because that's not package structure for Hibernate.  It's more likely that there was a conflict with a Hibernate class that's since been resolved.

Comment: hmm, @duffymo : thats what i told them, i just wish they tell me what was wrong so i can refuse further crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your HibernateUtil so it doesn't instantiate in a static block. Instead make it a singleton with a synchronized getInstance. Then

```
private static SessionFactory cache;

synchronized SessionFactory getInstance() throws SQLException {

if (cache != null) return cache;

// try/catch and rethrow SQLException
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc");
} Exception (e) {
throw new SQLException(e);
}
// Test connection with JDBC
// Create a non connection pooled raw connection, try/finally close it
// throw SQL Exception if it fails
testMe()

// finally create the sessionFactory
.... build your Configuration object
.... then 
try {
SessionFactory me = ....buildSessionFactory
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
throw new SQLException(e);
}
cache = me;
return cache;

}
```

Some comments: some people will prefer an unchecked exception, which is fine.
The reason I like doing the raw connection once is that on startup it tends to bollix up connection pool/hibernate less if the SQL Server happens to be done. Once they initialize successfully I've not had recovery issues. But that's a personal taste thing, and you could skip testMe() as well.

Point is this way you will SEE the Exception occurring, and I predict to you it will clearly implicate the connection to the hosting company :)

Comment: Thanks, I typed it in spontaneously, so please all forgive the dodgy syntax, etc :) Note I do recognize different philosophies on HibernateUtil implementations, but this one I find useful and it will definitely track down the issue with that hosting company. If throwing the exception as checked is bad, rethrow as an unchecked  but log first